# Rmarkdown: change default font size for code (Powerpoint output)

Tags: r-markdown, powerpoint, pandoc

When knitting an Rmarkdown document to Powerpoint, I do not understand why by default the inline code (or chunks code) is rendered in the presentation in font Courier **size 18pt**, whereas the rest of the non-code text is in font Calibri **size 28pt**.

I could only change the later using a custom template, but not the code appearance. Did I miss something?

Here is a simple example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Julien Roux"
date: "9/18/2019"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

Why is `inline code` appearing smaller?
````

Which results in this output slide after knitting in Rstudio (version 1.2.1578):

[image]

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 Patched (2019-05-14 r76503)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.0  htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.6.0     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.2      rmarkdown_1.15  knitr_1.24     
 [8] xfun_0.9        digest_0.6.20   evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], e.g. the code you used to produce this image.

Comment: Done, and I've added my session info

Comment: This seems to be https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4999. You would need a development version of pandoc to get a fix to that.

Comment: Good spot, thanks!

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: It seems so! (With R version 4.1.0, knitr 1.36, rmarkdown 2.11 and Rstudio 1.4.1717)